# Query polymer.dart custom property value

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

How can I query the value of a custom property in Polymer.dart 1.0?

I have:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  my-element {
    --my-color: #ffffff;
  }
</style>
```

Passing it on to a child element of `my-element` works fine, for example:

```
.header {
  --paper-toolbar-color: var(--my-color);
}
```

But how can I query the value from Dart in `my-element` in a way that works in all browsers?

I have tried `$['header'].customStyle['--paper-toolbar-color']` and the same on `this` and also for `--my-color`, but it does not work unless I first set the customStyle from Dart.

I have managed to work around it in Chrome by setting

```
.header {
  color: var(--my-color);
}
```

and then reading this with `$['header'].getComputedStyle().color;`, but Firefox returns the inherited colour value instead of the one from the custom property.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you currently can only read CSS variables declared in the current component but you can't read global CSS variables from inside a component.

If you have this in your header component:

```
<style>
  :host {
    --my-color: #ffffff;
  }

  .header {
    --paper-toolbar-color: var(--my-color);
  }
</style>
```

then you can read it with

```
customStyle['--my-color']
```

otherwise your workaround is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, unfortunately, `this.customStyle['--my-color'];` returns null when I declaratively set `:host { --my-color: #ffffff; }`.

Comment: I think to remember that there was another issue that this only works if the value was set using `this.customStyle['--my-color'] = 'someValue';`

Comment: Yes that works, but it unfortunately doesn't allow me to get hold of the theme colour passed in from outside the element. It seems strange that there is no way of reading the property, the custom property polyfill must have it tucked away somewhere...